# Is URL encoding still needed for foreign language in the URI path?

Tags: url, character-encoding

Take the following path pattern for a site:
`https://www.example.com/profile/[firstname].[lastname]/`

I don't want to anglicise a users name. If there's an arabic or chinese or greek user, I want to just put their name in the URL. It's far more user friendly. Wikipedia appears to be doing this already (e.g. [https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/Αθήνα](https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%91%CE%B8%CE%AE%CE%BD%CE%B1), https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%85%D9%83%D8%A9) and Google is saying it's fine (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=74FiBesPkI4) but I can't find any official documentation to back this up.

In 2023 and beyond, can we use foreign characters in the path and is there some documentation about this?

I've searched around but cannot find any up to date questions and answers about this. Cheers.